# Initialize AudioClip Object at Runtime Unity C# Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

In my application I have to display a list of tracks to the user of which he can select a particular track &  as a result this track will be played as background music.

Right now I have copied all tracks in Resources folder & I am loading selected track as an AudioClip object through this code:

```
Resources.Load("Childrens Songs - Twinkle Twinkle") as AudioClip;
```

This code works fine but once I create build file (apk file) of my project. The size of apk file increases to 174MB from 31Mb. This happens only when I copy my tracks in Resources folder. If I copy these tracks to any other folder than apk size is around 31mbs.

Is there any other way to initialize AudioClip object at runtime(means without copying in Resources & using Resources.Load())?

Also what could be the possible reason that apk size increases to 174mb from 31mb in case of  copying in Resources & using Resources.Load().

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other way. If you're doing any procedural generation, there is no other option but to use the Resources folder.

The reason your built project is smaller when you move the files out of the Resource folder is that if they are not used then they are ignored by the build. However, when you put them inside the Resource folder they are not ignored, because there is the potential that code will load them, thus your build will increase in size.

> In Unity you usually don't use path names to access assets, instead
>   you expose a reference to an asset by declaring a member-variable, and
>   then assign it in the inspector. When using this technique Unity can
>   automatically calculate which assets are used when building a player.
>   This radically minimizes the size of your players to the assets that
>   you actually use in the built game. When you place assets in
>   "Resources" folders this can not be done, thus all assets in the
>   "Resources" folders will be included in a build.

[**Unity API Resources Information**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but total size of my files(mp3 tracks) is around 15mb only.

Comment: If you don't believe me put your files in a normal folder and load them, then build the project. Then do the same without loading the files but putting them on the Resource folder. If the file sizes match then the answer is obvious.